# AsyncTask not performing as expected

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My logcat shows a problem in doInBackground() . It might be a problem with with the main thread of the UI being inside the doInBackground thread and not on the onPostExecute method, but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Many thanks

AllProductsActivity.java:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "192.168.1.68/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
09-23 04:16:12.898    8201-8274/com.example.androidhive E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 8201
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=192.168.1.68/android_connect/get_all_products.php
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
            at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:128)
            at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:105)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-23 04:16:13.018    8201-8201/com.example.androidhive E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{423ea0f0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-959,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:117)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is the code causing you the error `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);`. Put a breakpoint there and run the debugger and make sure all values are correct and correctly passed into `makeHttpRequest` method

Comment: here `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=192.168.1.68/android_connect/get_all_products.php` make sure your url is correct.

Comment: It seems all values are correct and my url must be that one since i'm using a local hosted database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the correct aswer is: The JSON query was returning the errors first then the query so when the APP tried to load the info from query, the JSON convert parsed the errors first thus failing because it was not a valid JSON query. Simply hiding the errors in the php file made EVERYTHING go smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Protocol is missing in the called url. In case of simple HTTP you can fix like:

```
private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.68/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
```

Comment: I still have the same error but a new one now: 09-23 05:06:17.399    9121-9251/com.example.androidhive E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of knowledge, but how can I make that call?

Comment: simply put the url of your service into your browser and see the result. Via command line (only *nix system) you can use `curl` or `wget` command.

Comment: Actually the correct aswer is: 
The JSON query was returning the errors first then the query so when the APP tried to load the info from query, the JSON convert parsed the errors first thus failing because it was not a valid JSON query. 
Simply hiding the errors in the php file made EVERYTHING go smoothly.